# swatch theme's footer can't stick to the bottom

Tags: css, wordpress, layout, themes, woothemes

I'm using a free wordpress theme from woothemes, Swatch theme. I don't know if somebody uses this theme,too. I've got involved some issue. When the posts is short. the theme's footer can't reach to the bottom. Left a piece of blank space. It's so ugly. So I wanna find a method to fix it. I've read some css books and googling for many times but I still can't find a way. So, I hope you guys can give me some suggetion. My programing knowledge is so poor. Sorry for that. Hope get your reply.

Best regards.

```
/* 2.1 Containers & Columns */
#wrapper  { background: transparent url(images/wrapper-bg-colourstrip.png) repeat-x left top; padding-top: 5px; } /* Top padding is the height of the colour strip image. */

#main{width:575px;}
#main.fullwidth, .layout-full #main, .col-full {width: 900px; margin:0 auto;}

#sidebar{width:250px;}
#sidebar .secondary { width:140px; } 

.entry img { max-width:565px; }
.layout-full .entry img { max-width:890px; }

.col-left { float: left; }
.col-right { float: right; }

.two-col-right #main { float:right; }
.two-col-right #sidebar { float:left; }



    /* 2.6 Footer */
#footer{padding: 30px 0 20px; background: url(images/bg-ripple-footer.png) repeat top left; color:#999;}
#footer p {}
#footer a { color: #ffffff; }
#footer #credit img{vertical-align:middle;}
#footer #credit span{display:none;}

#footer-widgets { margin-bottom: -5px; background: url(images/bg-ripple-footer-widgets.png) repeat top left; padding:10px 0; }
#footer-widgets .block { padding:20px 10px 0 10px; float:left; }
#footer-widgets .col-1 .block { width:100%; padding-left:0; }
#footer-widgets .col-2 .block { width:420px; padding-left: 20px; }
#footer-widgets .col-3 .block { width:270px; padding-left: 16px;  }
#footer-widgets .col-4 .block { width:200px; padding-left: 10px;  }
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help you without code?

Comment: Sorry for that, I paste part of the css file here.#wrapper  { background: transparent url(images/wrapper-bg-colourstrip.png) repeat-x left top; padding-top: 5px; } /* Top padding is the height of the colour strip image. */

#main{width:575px;}
#main.fullwidth, .layout-full #main, .col-full {width: 900px; margin:0 auto;}

#sidebar{width:250px;}
#sidebar .secondary { width:140px; } 

.entry img { max-width:565px; }
.layout-full .entry img { max-width:890px; }

.col-left { float: left; }
.col-right { float: right; }

.two-col-right #main { float:right; }
.two-col-right #sidebar { float:left; }

Comment: You'll want to edit your post to include the code. If you indent properly (4 spaces) it will format it for you.

Answer (score 0):

This demo displays a widely used method of implementing a sticky footer [http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).

The HTML setup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Body Content -->
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    <!-- Footer Content -->
</div>
```

This is the CSS that does it:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's   height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

Failing that you could try asking WooThemes for support.